# How to precisely set the surface thickness of the graph?

Tags: graphics3d, stl-format

I have a Mathematica ver 12.0

I would definitely like to convert the following graph to an STL file.

So I set the PlotPoints to 120 and the surface of the graph is very smooth.

```
 ContourPlot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y] Sin[z]+Sin[x] Cos[y] Cos[z]+Cos[x] Sin[y] Cos[z]+Cos[x] Cos[y] Sin[z]==0, {x,-2Pi,2Pi},{y,-2Pi,2Pi},{z,-2Pi,2Pi},Extrusion->1, Mesh->False, PlotPoints->120]
```

However, the thickness set in this graph is not as precise as the value of PlotPoints.

Is there a way to set the thickness precisely?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is `ContourPlot3D[
 Sin[x] Sin[y] Sin[z] + Sin[x] Cos[y] Cos[z] + Cos[x] Sin[y] Cos[z] + 
   Cos[x] Cos[y] Sin[z] == 0, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 
  2 Pi}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", 
 Method -> { "Extrusion" -> 1, "ExtrusionStyle" -> Directive[Red]}, 
 Mesh -> None]`  any better?

Comment: Yes. I do not want a surface. I want the thickness to be smoother.